How to open database connection asynchronously?
If connection times out, I see the error message, but the page with all the messages shows up only after the timeout. How to make the page show up at once and show "Opening database connection" before trying to connect?
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                ServerName.Text = "Opening database connection"; // ServerName is a label
                sqlclient.sqlconnection conn = new();
                conn.connectionstring=... // assume I initialized it
                conn.open
                ServerName.Text += "\nOpened successfully"; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ServerName.Text += $"\n{ex.Message}"; 
            }
}


don't put the db query in the constructor.  Also, it would be very helpful to know which DB you're using.

More the point: don't keep a single connection open the whole time. Do what you need and close the connection with using or await using, and do any data access asynchronously in some kind of OnLoad event.

This should work. Call this from the Page/Window Loaded Event
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       MainPage.Loaded += async (sender, e) =>
       {
         try
         {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ServerName.Text = "Opening database connection";
                // ServerName is a label
                sqlclient.sqlconnection conn = new();
                conn.connectionstring = "ConnectionString"; // assume I initialized 
                conn.open();
                ServerName.Text += "\nOpened successfully";
                // do Some Operation 
                conn.close();
            });
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServerName.Text += $"\n{ex.Message}";
        }
    };
  }


Don't do async void except for event handlers.

true -see updated solution above

Now you have an open connection that you did not close and cannot use. When this is done the local var will be out of scope.

@Fildor - Ok I have update it based on your point. But I have answered the main question.

Now it makes sense :) although it should make use of using.

@PalleDue this is now correct

@PalleDue "Don't do async void except for event handlers." -- Correct, but the async void delegate in this answer is an event handler. It handles the Page.Loaded event. I guess that your comment refers to an earlier revision of this answer.

Niall O'Dwyer regarding the latest (3rd) revision of your answer, you have an async delegate without any await, so the compiler will produce a warning CS1998.

@TheodorZoulias - I have added the await

Nice. You could consider improving the formatting of the code (indentation), as well as the syntax errors (missing semicolons and parentheses).

@TheodorZoulias formatting improved
